# SQL: Selecting top proportion of column and corresponding attributes in other columns

Tags: sql, presto

Say I have data like so

```
group,      city,  user,
nyc_frisbee, nyc,   joe,
nyc_frisbee, nyc,   ben,
nyc_frisbee,  sf,   tim,
sf_cooking,   sf,   tim,
sf_cooking,  atl,   jon,
```

My goal is to get

```
group,       top_city, prob
nyc_firsbee, nyc,      .66
sf_cooking,  sf,       .5
sf_ccoking,  atl,      .5
```

Edge case: In this table below, nyc_frisbee shows up only once because there is a single top city. However, sf_cooking shows up twice because sf and atl are tied.

How can I accomplish this in SQL?

What I have so far:

```sql
SELECT group, city, top/total AS prob
FROM (
     SELECT 
         group, 
         city, 
         freq,
         MAX(freq) OVER(PARTITION BY group) AS top,
         SUM(freq) OVER(PARTITION BY group) AS total
     FROM
         (SELECT group, city, COUNT(city) AS freq
          FROM mytable
          GROUP BY group, city) inner_query
     ) outer_query
WHERE outer.freq = outer.top
```

This doesn't behave the way that I intended...

```
group,       top_city, prob
nyc_firsbee, nyc,      .66
nyc_firsbee, sf,       .66
sf_cooking,  sf,       .5
sf_ccoking,  atl,      .5
```

So I'm getting one row per each unique group/city combination with the same prob value.

Comment: What is the output you're looking for? You've explained a lot of what you don't want, but not what you do.

Comment: See second code block :)

Comment: Ohhhh I get it now. I misread. My mistake.

Comment: Please TAG your RDBMS

Comment: Done @Stu (Presto)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about something like:

```
WITH x as (
  SELECT group, city, CAST(COUNT(*) AS FLOAT)/SUM(COUNT(*)) OVER(PARTITION BY group) AS prob
  FROM mytable
  GROUP BY group, city
)

SELECT x.*
FROM 
  x 
  INNER JOIN 
  (SELECT group, MAX(prob) maxprob FROM x GROUP BY group) y 
  ON 
    x.group = y.group AND
    x.prob = y.maxprob
```

We boil our group/cities down to

```
group,      city,  prob,
nyc_frisbee, nyc,   0.66,
nyc_frisbee,  sf,   0.33,
sf_cooking,   sf,   0.5,
sf_cooking,  atl,   0.5,
```

and alias as X, then we join it to a grouping of itself on the `group, max(prob)`. Because `sf_cooking, 0.5` is the max, the join matches twice, preserving the tie, but nyc's max is 0.66 which matches once, excluding the 0.33

Answer (score 1):

See if the following works for you. First calculating the probablity, then rank the groups ordered by the probablity, finally getting distinct rows.

```
with x as (
select *,
    Count(*) over(partition by group, City) * 1.0 / Count(*) over(partition by group) prob
from t
), r as (
    select *, dense_rank() over(partition by group order by prob desc) rn
    from x
)
select distinct group, city, prob
from r
where rn=1
```